Does ObservableCollection support cross thread use in Avalonia?
I am a novice to Avalonia. I've encountered with InvalidOperationException and I've found that's because I called ObservableCollection.Add() in another thread.I used Dispatcher.UIThread.Invoke() and successfully solve the problem.
But I'm still confused as I feel that I didn't call Dispatcher.UIThread.Invoke() before but still succeed in updating the collection.So,I make a demo to reproduce the problem,the result confuses me.
package version:
Avalonia 11.0.10  
Avalonia.Controls.Datagrid 11.0.10  

In this demo,I created an ObservableCollection and manually add item into it in another thread.To observable thread info,I created PrintThreadInfo to print thread info to console.
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; } = [];
    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task AddString()
    {
        PrintThreadInfo("relaycommand");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            PrintThreadInfo("task in relay command");
            Strings.Add("new string");
        });
        Dispatcher.UIThread.Invoke(() => PrintThreadInfo("UI"));
    }
    static void PrintThreadInfo(string threadName)
    {
        var currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        Console.WriteLine($"{threadName}:");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Thread ID: {currentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Is Background: {currentThread.IsBackground}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Thread Name: {currentThread.Name ?? "No Name"}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  Is Thread Pool Thread: {currentThread.IsThreadPoolThread}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

The view is very simple.I firstlly used ListBox though Datagrid was used in my project before:
<StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding  Strings}"/>
        <Button Content="Add a string!"
                Command="{Binding AddStringCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>

Then I clicked the button,strangely,the listbox corrected added an item.
And the console output:
relaycommand:
  Thread ID: 1
  Is Background: False
  Thread Name: No Name
  Is Thread Pool Thread: False

task in relay command:
  Thread ID: 8
  Is Background: True
  Thread Name: .NET TP Worker
  Is Thread Pool Thread: True

UI:
  Thread ID: 1
  Is Background: False
  Thread Name: No Name
  Is Thread Pool Thread: False

It seems that cross thread use is supported.But if I change ListBox into Datagrid,the InvalidOperationException comes again.
All discussions I found on this topic tell me to use Dispatcher.UIThread.Invoke() but how to explain the ListBox?
I just want to know if cross thread use is supported? Or it's a problem of the Avalonia Datagrid?Or it's actually Unsafe to directly edit obervablecollection in an NonUI thread,the success in ListBox is a coincidence?

Only reason you would marshal something to UI thread is if you were outside of that thread trying to interact with UI. That should not happen in a well designed MVVM application. ObservableCollection is not thread safe. If thread safety is needed, use a collection in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. Your test in my opinion is inconclusive, a better example would most likely show the same InvalidOperationException.

If I use Datagrid in Avalonia,the same InvalidOperationException appears.But if I use ListBox,no exception is shown.I just tested in WPF,both Datagrid and ListBox give NotSupportedException.So what confuses me is that,why there's no Exception in some cases in Avalonia even if I interactive with UI outside UI thread.

WPF has the BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization method to enable cross thread access for ObservableCollection. Avalonia does not seem to provide a similar feature, so the answer appears to be: no - cross thread use is not supported.

AFAIK, there is no guarantee of exceptions on cross thread access to UI elements. It may throw, or it could work, or do just about anything else. If you write multi threaded code you need to make sure it is thread safe. You cannot rely on the compiler or even testing to ensure safety. Threading issues can cause random and infrequent bugs, and may result in incorrect values rather than crashes, making them even harder to detect and fix.
